# Typoscript content localization

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I am developing a TYPO3 website with multilanguage support. I am using TemplaVoila for template mapping. Site works in both languages. But **content added with Typoscript in TemplaVoila mapping is rendered only in default language, in other languages content from Typoscript is missing.**

here is my typoscript:

```
    lib.autherInfo = CONTENT
    lib.autherInfo {
      table = tt_content
  select {
            selectFields = cruser_id
         }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {

        10 = RECORDS
        10{
          source.field = cruser_id 
          tables = be_users
          dontCheckPid = 1
          conf.be_users = COA
          conf.be_users {
            10 = TEXT
            10.field = realName
            10.noTrimWrap = ||, |
            15 = RECORDS
            15{
                  source.field = usergroup 
                  tables = be_groups
                  dontCheckPid = 1
                  conf.be_groups = COA
                  conf.be_groups {
                  10 = TEXT
                  10.field = title
                  10.noTrimWrap = ||, |
              }
            }
            20 = TEXT
            20.dataWrap = <span><a href="mailto:{field:email}" >{field:email}</a></span>      
           }
         }
      }
    }
    lib.autherInfo.wrap = <p>by:&nbsp|</p>
```

Output mark up of above typoscript is:

```
    <p>by:&nbsp;Administrator, admin, <span><a href="mailto:admin@kultur.com">admin@kultur.com</a></span></p>
```

In other languages output is:

```
    <p>by:&nbsp;</p>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing your typo3 language configuration. You can set a **language fallback** at least to get some output. Example configuration

```
config {
    linkVars = L
    sys_language_uid = 0
    language = de
    locale_all = de_DE
    htmlTag_langKey = de
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated

    linkVars := addToList(L)

    uniqueLinkVars = 1  
    // content fallback
    sys_language_fallBackOrder = 1,0
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback ; 1,0
    sys_language_overlay = 1
    sys_language_content = 1    
}
```

Try setting

```
sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
```

to

```
sys_language_overlay = 0
```

Comment: sys_language_overlay = 0;  will render : <p>by:&nbsp;Administrator, admin, <span><a href="mailto:admin@kultur.com">admin@kultur.com</a></span></p>    always. In other languages for Example in Danish I want   to render <p>Af:&nbsp;Administrator, admin, <span><a href="mailto:admin@kultur.com">admin@kultur.com</a></span></p>.

Comment: Note the change of 'by' to 'Af'

Comment: I don't want to display nontranslated page content. That is why I use 'sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated'

Comment: So there is no translated version for your content, this is why it is not displayed

Comment: No, I created  translation of page and content is also translated.

Comment: But in your TS "by" is not translated at all, it is hard coded.

Comment: ok, so I did this: lib.autherInfo.wrap.lang.dk = <p>Af:&nbsp|</p>

Comment: Now In English content precieded by a 'By' is displayed. And in danish only Af: is displayed.

Comment: then you have to do lib.autherInfo.wrap.lang.en = <p>By:&nbsp|</p> also

Comment: before 'lib.autherInfo.wrap.lang.dk = <p>Af:&nbsp|</p>' I wrote this: lib.autherInfo.wrap = <p>By:&nbsp|</p>. Since english is the default language, and it works. In danish only 'Af:' is displayed without content.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18050/discussion-between-harish-anchu-and-artworkad)